# How to sync the deleted artifacts from local repo to remote repository in artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I have two artifactory instances. Let's assume the first one is ABC and the other is XYZ.
On ABC(abc.arti.com), I have a local repository and on XYZ(xyz.arti.com), I have the remote repo which is pointing to the local repo in ABC.

If the client sends the "download artifact" request to xyz.arti.com, it checks the cache in the XYZ, if it is not available and goes to ABC and saves the artifacts in the XYZ and then sent it to the client. Now, If I delete the artifact from the ABC, the same artIfact is not getting deleted in the XYZ. The same artifact is still available on the XYZ after deleting it on the local repo.
How to sync the deleted artifacts on both the repositories?

Answer (score 1):

Please be informed that Artifactory smart remote repositories provide an option to identify the absence of the artifacts from the actual source.
Reference: [Source absence detection](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Smart+Remote+Repositories#:%7E:text=Source%20absence%20detection,access%20to%20it.). This would be overridden if a live deletion sync is happening.

As the artifacts are locally cached in the remote instance (Let's say XYZ as you have described above), the artifacts would remain intact until a manual [Zap Cache](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-ZappingCaches) being executed [or] until the expiry of the [Metadata Retrieval Cache Period](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-ZappingCaches:%7E:text=Metadata%20Retrieval%20Cache%20Timeout,value%20is%C2%A060%20seconds.).